# Updating SQL row on the basis of values from previous row

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert-update

I want to update row value which have some portion from previous row value. ( Basically I need to find carry over effect).

I am using `While loop` or `cursor` to do the same but it is taking alot of time as the update statement runs number of rows times.

Please suggest me a good efficient way to find out carry over effect. Below is the example of `dataset` with 0.2 carry over effect.

```
WeekNumber Var1 carry_over_effect_0.2
1           10          10
2           30          30+0.2*10
3           80          80+(30+0.2*10)*0.2
```

and so on

I want one more addition as given in example below

```
Brand    WeekNumber Var1 carry_over_effect_0.2
x         1           10          10
x         2           30          30+0.2*10
x         3           80          80+(30+0.2*10)*0.2
y         1           40          40
y         2           50          50 + (40*0.2)
```

and so on...
There may to one or more key variable as Brand is here which divides the complete set into two or more subsets.

Comment: you can do by 1st select stmnt for last value, where u get last carry_over_Value and then insert or update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the ordering is defined by `WeekNumber`, and that this is sequential with no gaps. Rather than doing an update, why not just perform the calculations during select (this way, you don't have to worry about the calculation being out of date):

```
declare @t table (WeekNumber int, Var1 int)
insert into @t (WeekNumber, Var1) values
(1,           10),
(2,           30),
(3,           80)

;with CarryOvers as (
    select WeekNumber,Var1,CONVERT(decimal(38,4),Var1) as CarryOver from @t where WeekNumber=1
    union all
    select t.WeekNumber,t.Var1,CONVERT(decimal(38,4),t.Var1 + (0.2*co.CarryOver))
    from @t t inner join CarryOvers co on t.WeekNumber = co.WeekNumber+1
)
select * from CarryOvers option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Results:

```
WeekNumber  Var1        CarryOver
----------- ----------- ---------------------------------------
1           10          10.0000
2           30          32.0000
3           80          86.4000
```

---

`UPDATE` version:

```
declare @t table (WeekNumber int, Var1 int,CarryOver decimal(38,4))
insert into @t (WeekNumber, Var1) values
(1,           10),
(2,           30),
(3,           80)

;with CarryOvers as (
    select WeekNumber,Var1,CONVERT(decimal(38,4),Var1) as CarryOver from @t where WeekNumber=1
    union all
    select t.WeekNumber,t.Var1,CONVERT(decimal(38,4),t.Var1 + (0.2*co.CarryOver))
    from @t t inner join CarryOvers co on t.WeekNumber = co.WeekNumber+1
)
update t set CarryOver = co.CarryOver
from @t t inner join CarryOvers co on t.WeekNumber = co.WeekNumber
option (maxrecursion 0)

select * from @t
```

But I'd repeat I'd recommend against doing this unless it's a proven performance issue to just run the `SELECT` during normal usage - any other `UPDATE`s to the table now require this `UPDATE` to be run immediately afterwards, so you're adding a considerable performance cost for each `UPDATE`.

---

With `Brand` added:

```
declare @t table (Brand char(1),WeekNumber int, Var1 int)
insert into @t (Brand,WeekNumber, Var1) values
('x',1,           10),
('x',2,           30),
('x',3,           80),
('y',1,40),
('y',2,50)

;with CarryOvers as (
    select Brand,WeekNumber,Var1,CONVERT(decimal(38,4),Var1) as CarryOver from @t where WeekNumber=1
    union all
    select t.Brand,t.WeekNumber,t.Var1,CONVERT(decimal(38,4),t.Var1 + (0.2*co.CarryOver))
    from @t t inner join CarryOvers co on t.WeekNumber = co.WeekNumber+1 and t.Brand = co.Brand
)
select * from CarryOvers
order by Brand,WeekNumber option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response..right weeknumber is used for ordering with no gap.. Solution you are giving will take alot of time when I am running it on more than 200 thousands rows..

Comment: @user2239073 - well, if you really want to store it, you can write an `UPDATE` that `JOIN`s `CarryOvers` back to the original table and assign the value back - but how often do you query this table for all 200000 rows?

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever when I am running the above code for more than 100 rows I am getting ERROR:  Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: @user2239073 - specify `option (maxrecursion 0)` at the end of the `select` - I've edited it into my answer too.

Comment: It works great..can you please change it to update. I require to update the column carryover in my table..

Comment: hey thanks it is working great..I will impleant this in my ongoing procedure..thanks alot..

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever I wnat to upgrade my question is it possible with this solution if I add new key variable which divide this set into two or more subsets and then calculate carryover seperately.?

Comment: @user2239073 - just add that extra key column into the `JOIN` condition's `ON` clauses and the `SELECT` list of the CTE. - that will keep each set separated.

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever can you please give me an example

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever I have updated my question for the refrence

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. But consider using TRIGGERS

I am not sure about this working.

```
CREATE TRIGGER NAME
BEFORE INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_nAME) > 0
    BEGIN
INSERT INTO TABLE-NAME
SELECT NEW.WEEKNUMBER, NEW.VAR1, (NEW.VAR1+S.CARRY_OVER_EFFECT *0.2) AS         CARRY_OVER_EFFECT
FROM 
TABLE-NAME S
WHERE S.WEEKNUMBER + 1= NEW.WEEK_NUMBER;
END
```

Comment: Hi Santosh, I want to dynamically update my rows which are dependent on previous row values. for example If variable value in row 1 is 20 then its corresponding value should be 20 and variable value in row 2 is 30 then its corresponding value should be 30+0.2*20, If percentage taken is .20